# Extracting probabilities from a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I have plotted a PDF normal distribution function for 8000 data points on mathematica using

$Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[64, 8.5333333], x], \{x, 20, 100\}]$.

[image: Normal distribution of 8000 data points]

I want to find a range of values of $A_i$ of around 5MHz with a high probability of containing just one data point. I.e. if I look in a 5MHz section of the distribution, I should only find one data point in this particular section. I would like this to have a high value of $A_i$. I realise that I need to look at the edge of the distribution, but is this done by integrating the area under the curve, and if so how does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N$ be the total number of data points and $P$ the PDF. The probability that the interval $[A_1,A_2]$ contains precisely $n$ data points is
$$\left(\begin{matrix}N \\ n \end{matrix}\right)\left(\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da\right)^n \left(1-\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da\right)^{N-n}$$
This is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

How high can we make the probability that the interval contains precisely 1 data point?
$$\left(\begin{matrix}N \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da\right) \left(1-\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da\right)^{N-1}$$
$$N\left(\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da\right) \left(1-\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da\right)^{N-1}$$
Let us call $\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da=p$
$$Np \left(1-p\right)^{N-1}$$
To maximize,
$$\frac{d}{dp}Np \left(1-p\right)^{N-1}=0$$
$$-N (1 - p)^{N-2} (N p-1)=0$$
$$N p=1$$
You maximize the probability that the interval contains precisely 1 data point if
$$N\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da=1$$
in which case the probability that the interval contains precisely 1 data point is
$$\left(1-1/N\right)^{N-1}$$
For large $N$, this approaches $1/e$.

How to pick $A_1,A_2$ such that $\int_{A_1}^{A_2} P(a) da=1/N$? This you will have to do numerically. You can choose an interval symmetric around 5MHz and solve
$$\int_{5\text{MHz}-x}^{5\text{MHz}+x} P(a) da=1/N$$